# Golang json decodes based on static type not dynamic type

Tags: json, go

I thought `json.Marshal` used reflection to look at the passed type and then decoded accordingly. However, if I have a variable with static type `any` that actually holds a struct and I pass that to `json.Unmarshal` it changes the pointer to point to a `map[string]any` rather than filling in my struct.

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Foo struct {
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Number int    `json:"number"`
}

const jsonStr = `{"name": "testing", "number": 22}`

func decodeAny(dest any) error {
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), dest)
}

func getFooAny() any {
    return Foo{}
}

func main() {
    dest := Foo{}
    err := decodeAny(&dest)
    fmt.Printf("err: %v\n", err) // err is nil
    fmt.Printf("dest %v of type %T\n", dest, dest)  // dest is a Foo

    dest2 := getFooAny()
    fmt.Printf("Initial type of dest2: %T\n", dest2) // dest2 is a Foo
    fmt.Printf("Checking with reflect: %v\n", reflect.TypeOf(dest2)) // TypeOf things dest2 is aFoo
    err = decodeAny(&dest2)
    fmt.Printf("err: %v\n", err) // Err is nil
    fmt.Printf("dest2 %v of type %T\n", dest2, dest2) // dest2 is now a map[string]any
}
```

If you'd like to try it, here's a link to the above code in the Go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/yDI7wYZp5Zx

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, you are passing in a `*Foo` to unmarshal, so it knows what to do with it.

In the second case, you are passing in a `*any` that does not contain an addressable object to unmarshal, so `json.Unmarshal` builds a `map[string]any`.

You should pass an interface that contains a `*Foo`:

```
foo := Foo{}
intf := any(&foo)
decodeAny(intf)
```

This should work.

Comment: In the 2nd case I'm passing a pointer to an `Foo` as an `any` (not a `*any`), but if you call `reflect.TypeOf` it'll return `*Foo`. So, while the static type is `any` the dynamic type is still `*Foo` and I thought `json.Unmarshal` used the dynamic type. Indeed, the type signature of `Unmarshal` has it the destination as an `any`.So I'm wondering *why* that's happening. Isn't `json.Unmarshal` using `reflect` to get the type?

Comment: No, you are passing in `*any`

Comment: You can see on the `Printf` lines before the call to `decodeAny` that the `reflect.TypeOf` type of `dest2` is `Foo`. Why then is the `reflect.TypeOf(&dest2)` a `*any` rather than a `*Foo`. For that matter, since `decodeAny`'s parameter type is `any` why is its dynamic type `*Foo` when I pass `&dest` but `*any` when I pass `&dest2` given that they both initially have a `reflect.TypeOf` of `Foo`?

Comment: You are passing a pointer to an interface, but the thing that implements the interface is not a pointer.  json.Unmarshal *can't* modify it (since it's not a pointer).  If you change getFooAny to return `&Foo{}` then it will work as expected

Comment: "If you change getFooAny to return &Foo{} then it will work as expected..." Yes, that does work. With the original `getFooAny` if I do `x := getFooAny()` then `reflect.TypeOf(x)` is, correctly, `Foo`. Given that, I was expecting `reflect.TypeOf(&x)` to be `*Foo` rather than `*interface{}`. So static type of `any` gets correctly resolved to the underlying type when that type isn't a pointer but it seems, understandably, that if it's a pointer Go isn't going to dereference that pointer to see the type that it points to; it's just going to trust the static type information.